# What does using a "." without an object in Android (or java) mean?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I am not sure but this is probably a java question and not specific to android. In the Android SDK, when I type in a "." at a blank line, it shows me an options menu:

[image]

The MyThread class is declared inside the MainActivity class (which extends Activity and implements some other interfaces for the UI). Normally this menu shows up when "." operator is placed after an object, and it shows the member data and functions declared in the class, of which that object is an instance of. However, there is no object here but still it is showing me this menu. Why is it doing that? If I just select a function and place it here, which object's function is it that gets executed?

Also, placing this "." in position 1 shows me an error. Position 1 is just inside the MainActivity class. Why does it show error here, but not at the position shown in the picture?

Comment: Isn't this just an illegal start of an expression? (although initially it behaves like this. )

Comment: It looks like if I actually place a function or a variable from that list in that position, it just shows an error at the "." . But if it is an error, why does it show the menu in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` will bring up the autocomplete-help in eclipse when you're **inside** your class (position 1 is outside your class, so it will give an error/warning instead) - all the methods you see are methods that your class inherits from its superclasses, and are available to you to use or override. All objects of classes you make in Java are actually subclasses of Object, and since you extended thread as well, you get a good amount of different methods from those to choose from.

**EDIT:**

The `.` will only work in inner classes or methods, it would seem - if you try to use `Ctrl + Space` at position 1, it should bring up a context-menu similar to what you get with `.` in other places. It's also worth mentioning that this is actually a feature of Eclipse (generally referred to as auto assist or content assist), the IDE, and not the Java programming language itself. To be fair, most good IDEs will have similar features, so it's an easy mistake to make :)

You can take a closer look at this and chance your preferences under

`Window -> Preferences -> JAVA -> Editor -> ContentAssist`, although I reccomend not fiddling with the default settings unless you have some very specific thing you want to change.

Comment: Position 1 is inside the MainActivity class. Shouldn't it show the methods inside Activity?

Comment: Good point, I completely missed that we were inside the MainActivity. Hmm, I would have thought that the auto-assist would have brought up a list of available methods from the MainActivity's imports instead, but that's apparently not the case. I've just tried replicating it on a project of my own, and I'm seeing the same thing as you are now.

Comment: @Aniket Thakur's answer seems to give some explanation too. Can you get any ideas from it?

Comment: I just checked myself too, and doing ctrl+spacebar inside position 1 seems to bring out the menu, only the "." character doesn't do it

Comment: I've updated my answer after a bit of research. I hope it's sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse default settings, the dot calls content assist, there'll be methods popup which can be overwrite from the father class, which is Thread in your code, and from all class extends Object, there're methods from Object class can be overwrite, you may see that from the grey comment after the method name.

Comment: so the "." is more of a command for eclipse than a java construct?

Comment: Yes, you can see your key binding from Window->Perferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist, you'll see there's a '.' in the Auto Activation section.

You can set your shortcut in General->Keys, search content assist, set a shortcut for this one, will help you code faster.

Answer (score 2):

Feature is called auto complete. Most IDE's support that.

```
What does using a “.” without an object in Android (or java) mean?
```

Your question is a bit ambiguous. You have just placed a dot and IDE tried to auto complete it. But in general even in a black line if you execute auto complete(Ctrl + space) in eclipse/Intellij IDEA you will get the same popup.

Generally dot means accessing a static variable or invoking a method. So IDE gives possible drop down.

Comment: I didn't know about ctrl+space thanks for that. I didn't know "." behaved like a keyboard shortcut for eclipse I thought it showing the context menu probably meant some java class-object concept I hadn't understood

Answer (score 1):

The `.`  is one of the shortcut to content assist, that's why you se some suggestions on what you could possibly right next. When you typed an object variable then a dot, it suggests methods or public fields froms that object. when you type it on a new line it suggest methods ready to be overriden in the current class  ...

By default, the character `(`  does also the same :

```
Completion can be triggered by user request or can be automatically triggered when the "(" or "." character is typed:

public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
    return new char[] { '.', '(' };
}
```

from :  [Eclipse content assist help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_contentassist.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In java "." is an operator which is use to relate any instance, variable, methord or etc...  to any instance, class or interface type.